# Is there a clean way to retain information while unwrapping a JSON object with Aeson?

Tags: json, haskell, aeson

I’m attempting to parse a JSON object which is described by the following “model schema”:

```
{
  "(archived|active)_org": {
    "id": "",
    "description": "",
    "reference": "",
    "bucket_name": "",
    "version": 0
  }
}
```

(Taken directly from the [API documentation](https://api.subledger.com/v2/index.html#!/orgs.json/get_org).)

I’m trying to use Aeson to parse this into the following type:

```
data Org = Org { active :: Bool
               , orgId :: Text
               , description :: Maybe Text
               , reference :: Maybe Text
               , version :: Int
               } deriving (Show, Eq)
```

I got as far as this:

```
instance FromJSON Org where
  parseJSON (Object v) = do
    Just (Object v') <- v .: "active_org"
    orgId <- v' .: "id"
    description <- v' .:? "description"
    reference <- v' .:? "reference"
    version <- v' .: "version"
    return $ Org True orgId description reference version
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```

That implementation works as long as the JSON consumed is tagged as an "active_org", but of course fails if provided an "archived_org". How do I generalize to cover both cases, and change the first argument to the `Org` value constructor depending on if it’s an "active_org" or an "archived_org"?

Comment: Use the `Alternative`/`MonadPlus` instances of `Parser` : `(v .: "active_org") <|> (v .: "archived_org")`. If you need, you can tell which branch was taken with e.g. `((True,) <$> (v .: "active_org")) <|> ((False,) <$> (v .: "archived_org"))`.

Comment: @user2407038 If you’d like to write that up as an answer, I would happily accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From an excellent comment by @user2407038, I got it working with the following:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TupleSections #-}

instance FromJSON Org where
  parseJSON (Object v) = ((True,) <$> (v .: "active_org"))
                     <|> ((False,) <$> (v .: "archived_org"))
                     >>= inner
    where inner (b, Object v') = Org b
                             <$> v' .: "id"
                             <*> v' .:? "description"
                             <*> v' .:? "reference"
                             <*> v' .: "version"
          inner (_, _) = mzero
  parseJSON _ = mzero
```